# Using Intersect function with enum Objects

Tags: c#, .net, enums

I got these Objects

```
enum ObjType { One, X, Two, Y, Three, Z}
List<ObjType> typeList
```

I want to make a condition like "if typeList doesnt contain a type like X, Y, Z do something", for that i have:

```
List<ObjType> typeExceptions = { ObjType.X, ObjType.Y, ObjType.Z}

if ( !typeList.Intersect(typeExceptions).Any() )
{
    //do something
}
```

Is there any cleaner way to do this without having the "type exceptions" hardcoded?

Comment: How would you not have the `typeExceptions` hardcoded? You have to specify which ones you are looking for somewhere.

Comment: I dunno if its possible, but i was aiming for something like having another object that "extends" ObjType (but doesn't have the whole enum values) and use Contains(ExceptionType)

Comment: I don't really see anything wrong with your current solution, to be honest. Anything more clever would complicate it.

Comment: Derive enum from int, then make all "errortypes" an uneven value.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: @JohnSaunders it was not my signature... i wrote it myself

Comment: @HélderGonçalves Which you shouldn't be doing; we don't want people to manually type out a signature to all of their posts; it's noise.  Your user card is your signature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `[Flags]` than you can apply a basic bitwise operations on these flags!

```
[Flags]
enum Days2
{
  None = 0x0,
  Sunday = 0x1,
  Monday = 0x2,
  Tuesday = 0x4,
  Wednesday = 0x8,
  Thursday = 0x10,
  Friday = 0x20,
  Saturday = 0x40
 }
```

Notes:
  - This will apply bitwise operations on the values.

AND:

```
 var meetingDays = Days2.Tuesday & Days2.Thursday;
```

Or:

```
meetingDays = Days2.Tuesday | Days2.Thursday;
```

Remove:

```
// Remove a flag using bitwise XOR. this will remove the tuesday from the week!
meetingDays = meetingDays ^ Days2.Tuesday;
```

Not:

```
meetingDays = meetingDays ~Days2.Tuesday;
```

You have to take care also on the Flag enum values must be 2powern 0, 1, 2, 4,  etc.

I have changed the example I have got the code from microsoft side:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/vstudio/cc138362.aspx

This link is also very nice:
http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2010/07/22/c-fundamentals-combining-enum-values-with-bit-flags.aspx

Comment: honestly i prefer the asker solution; anything else is just complicating it

Comment: @LuisFilipe what is complicated? this is one of the basic C# concepts.

Comment: you're right; you can even declare in the enum itself meetingDays = Days2.Tuesday | Days2.Thursday

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why using hex instead of decimal base?

Comment: @LuisFilipe The whole point is that the values are powers of two, so that their bitcodes are 0001, 0010, 0100 etc. `Thursday = 0x10` shows it is a 1 followed by four zeroes. `Thursday = 16` is slightly more error prone to code and maintain. I prefer `Thursday = 1 << 4` though, even simpler.

Comment: @Wolfzoon with the new version C# 7 this can really easy done a new feature is called Pattern Matching solve those problems in one line but i think the complete version of Pattern Matching will be in C# 8 and not 7

Answer (score 0):

While [Bassam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19252227) gives some good general info about how to solve the problem, it doesn't connect the dots between the problem and a realistic solution.

Here is an implementation that demonstrates an intersect operation using the bit operations that he specified using a `[Flags]` enum, a constant (to hold the values to intersect with) and an extension method.

### Flags Enum

```
[Flags]
public enum ObjType
{
    One   = 0x01,
    X     = 0x02,
    Two   = 0x04,
    Y     = 0x08,
    Three = 0x10,
    Z     = 0x20
}
```

### Extension Methods

```
public static class ObjTypeExtensions
{
    public static readonly ObjType Exceptions = ObjType.X | ObjType.Y | ObjType.Z;

    public static ObjType IntersectWith(this ObjType objType, ObjType value)
    {
        return objType & value;
    }

    public static bool Any(this ObjType objType, ObjType value)
    {
        return (objType & value) != 0;
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
var test1 = ObjType.One | ObjType.Three | ObjType.X;
var result1 = test1.IntersectWith(ObjTypeExtensions.Exceptions);
// result1 == ObjType.X

var test2 = ObjType.Two | ObjType.Y | ObjType.Z;
var result2 = test2.IntersectWith(ObjTypeExtensions.Exceptions);
// result2 == ObjType.Y | ObjType.Z
```

To test whether there are any intersecting values, simply call the Any() method to get the answer.

```
bool any2 = test2.Any(ObjTypeExtensions.Exceptions);
// any2 == true

var test3 = ObjType.One | ObjType.Three;
bool any3 = test3.Any(ObjTypeExtensions.Exceptions);
// any3 == false
```